# Eclipse EPIC Import Errors

Tags: eclipse, perl, module, dependencies, epic

I am fairly new at perl development. I thought before i dive into coding let me setup my IDE. I downloaded Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2 , EPIC 0.5.46 and Strawberry Perl 5 version 18.

I imported an existing sample project into my workspace. The project is a hierarchy of packages , perl modules and perl scripts. All perl modules and files importing resources from other modules and packages errored out. Following are the kind of errors I am getting:

```
Can't locate Mail/Address.pm in @INC
```

The line in module "AddrList.pm" that resulted in the above error is:

```
use Mail::Address;
```

Following is the heirarchy of these two modules in the project

```
Project -> Lib -> Mail -> MailFold -> AddrList.pm

Project -> Lib -> Mail -> Address.pm
```

I have had import errors previously in Java for which one would either change built path or correct package names.

I have tried

Project -> Properties -> Perl Include Path

and provided the location my projects lib folder.The errors still persist.

Appreciate your assistance / comments .  Thanks !!!!!

Comment: Re "and provided the location my projects lib folder", Where's the rest of the error message? Is said directory listed in the error message? Make sure the case is correct.

Comment: Yes the directory is listed in the error message (rest of the error message only lists what are the contents of @INC). The case seems to be alright too.

Comment: One other thing ,the project runs fine outside of EPIC . Which means there are no issues with Module references/imports. In eclipse I get a large number of errors (like 58 errors ). Weird thing is , many of the errors go away once i open up individual files.Has anyone observed this behavior before.

Answer (score 0):

First, the paths in *Project->Properties->Perl Include Path* shall be **relative to your project dir** (nothing says this. I found it by seeing the command lines of `perl` processes that EPIC spawns).

Then, you also need to specify path to your Perl interpreter in *Window->Preferences->Perl* (unless it's reachable with the default `perl`) - EPIC uses it to get the system `@INC` entries.